# Run method before each test

Tags: java, testing, testng

Im using `testng 6.11` and writing tests in the following test class:

```
public class MyTest{

    public int i;

    public void init(){
        //initialize i
    }

    @Test
    public void test1(){
        //test some
    }

    @Test
    public void test2(){
        //Here I need fresh value of i as it would be
        //right after invocation of init()
        //...
        //test something else
    }
}
```

Is it possible to make testng run `init()` method before invocation of each test in a test class?

Comment: It seems to me like you should read [some documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html). This question is very lazy - I would expect more from a user with over 5k reputation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Annotate `init()` with `@BeforeMethod` annotation. See http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotations

Comment: The linked page mentions nothing of the sort.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, your can use the annotation for that

@BeforeTest: The annotated method will be run before any test method belonging to the classes inside the  tag is run.

Comment: Just tried... doesnt work. But putting the method invocation explicitly in the beginnig of each method works fine

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@BeforeMethod` annotatation to execute any method before every test.

[Example](https://dzone.com/articles/testng-beforemethod-annotation)